# vector in clojure and type casting

Tags: clojure

```
 (= ":bar:foo" ((fn [[a b]] (str b a)) [:foo :bar]))
```

I have several question about this clojure code.

1. what's the deal about `:` in front each element in vector?
2. How can str cast `:foo` to string type `":foo"` ?

Thanks

Comment: 1. Those (the whole elements) are keywords 2. Use `name` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In clojure, such element called as keywords. Keywords evaluate to themselves, and often used as accessors for the values.

```
(def x {:a 10, :b 20})
```

You can check the type:

```
user=> (class :foo)
clojure.lang.Keyword
user=> (type :foo)
clojure.lang.Keyword
```

You can convert it to str: Be cautious that `:` in the front.

```
user=> (str :foo)
":foo"
```

If you want to get only the name string from the keyword, then:

```
user=> (name :foo)
"foo"
```

Or you can create a keyword from str:

```
user=> (keyword "foo")
:foo
```